# Problem with tac_plus.cfg on Tacacs GUI with error ' /opt/tacacsgui/tac_plus.cfg_test:47: Unrecognized keyword 'host''

Tags: server, tac

I got  error when try to apply my tacacs gui configuration, i try this configuration with different server on localhost and it's working but not on my first server tacacs

/opt/tacacsgui/tac_plus.cfg_test:47: Unrecognized keyword 'host'

Please help me fix this issue, this my tac_plus.cfg :

```
    id = spawnd {
####SPAWND####

  listen = { port = 49 }
} ##END OF SPAWND
id = tac_plus { ##START GLOBAL CONFIGURATION
####GENERAL CONFIGURATION####

  ###MANUAL CONFIGURATION START###
log = accounting_log {
    destination =  "| /opt/tacacsgui/parser/tacacs_parser.sh accounting" 
    log separator = "|!|"} 
log = authentication_log {
    destination = "| /opt/tacacsgui/parser/tacacs_parser.sh authentication"
    log separator = "|!|"}
log = authorization_log {
    destination = "| /opt/tacacsgui/parser/tacacs_parser.sh authorization"
    log separator = "|!|"}
  ###MANUAL CONFIGURATION END###
  accounting log = accounting_log
  authentication log = authentication_log
  authorization log = authorization_log
  connection timeout = 600
  context timeout = 3600
  password max-attempts = 1
  password backoff = 1
  separation tag = "*"
  skip conflicting groups = yes
  skip missing groups = yes
  ####MAVIS GENERAL SETTINGS####

  user backend = mavis
  login backend = mavis chpass
  pap backend = mavis
  mavis module = external {
    exec = /opt/tacacsgui/mavis/app.php
  } #END OF MAVIS GLOBAL SETTINGS
  ####LIST OF ACL####
  ####LIST OF DEVICE GROUPS####

  host = defaultGroup {
  welcome banner = "Unauthorized access is prohibited!"
  motd banner = "Today is a perfect day! Have a nice day!"
  failed authentication banner = "Go away! Unauthorized access is prohibited!"
} #END OF defaultGroup

host = datacomm {
  key = "telkomcel"
  enable = clear telkomcel
  default group = datacomm_full
} #END OF datacomm

host = servicesolution {
  key = "telkomcel"
  enable = clear telkomcel
} #END OF servicesolution
  ####LIST OF HOSTS####

  host = SW-CORE2 {
    address = "192.168.101.12/32"
    key = "telkomcel"
    enable = clear telkomcel
    template = datacomm
  } #END OF SW-CORE2

  host = PE2-INET-AIM {
    address = "192.168.101.10/32"
    key = "telkomcel"
    enable = clear telkomcel
    template = servicesolution
  } #END OF PE2-INET-AIM

  host = SRDLI02 {
    address = "192.168.101.14/32"
    key = "telkomcel"
    enable = clear telkomcel
    template = datacomm
  } #END OF SRDLI02
  ####LIST OF USER GROUPS####

  group = datacomm_full {
    #### LDAP Groups List #### DistinguishedName ###
    ### CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=telkomcel,DC=tl ###
    enable = clear telkomcel
    default service = permit
    ###Service full START###
    service = shell {
      set priv-lvl = 15
      default attribute = permit
      default cmd = permit
    } #END OF Cisco Router/Switch Service
    ###Service full END###
  } #END OF datacomm_full

  group = servicesolution_full {
    #### LDAP Groups List #### DistinguishedName ###
    ### CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=telkomcel,DC=tl ###
    enable = clear telkomcel
    server = deny SW-CORE2
    server = deny SRDLI02
    default service = permit
    ###Service full START###
    service = shell {
      set priv-lvl = 15
      default attribute = permit
      default cmd = permit
    } #END OF Cisco Router/Switch Service
    ###Service full END###
  } #END OF servicesolution_full

  group = servicesolution_read {
    #### LDAP Groups List #### DistinguishedName ###
    ### CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=telkomcel,DC=tl ###
    enable = clear telkomcel
    server = deny SW-CORE2
    server = deny SRDLI02
    default service = permit
    ###Service read_only START###
    service = shell {
      set priv-lvl = 3
      default attribute = permit
      default cmd = permit
    } #END OF Cisco Router/Switch Service
    ###Service read_only END###
  } #END OF servicesolution_read

  group = datacomm_read {
    #### LDAP Groups List #### DistinguishedName ###
    ### CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=telkomcel,DC=tl ###
    enable = clear telkomcel
    default service = permit
    ###Service read_only START###
    service = shell {
      set priv-lvl = 3
      default attribute = permit
      default cmd = permit
    } #END OF Cisco Router/Switch Service
    ###Service read_only END###
  } #END OF datacomm_read
  ####LIST OF USERS####

  user = 91007 {
    login = mavis # LDAP
    member = datacomm_read
    pap = login # Clone login
    enable = login # Clone login
    default service = permit
    ###Service full START###
    service = shell {
      set priv-lvl = 15
      default attribute = permit
      default cmd = permit
    } #END OF Cisco Router/Switch Service
    ###Service full END###
  } #END OF 91007

  user = 88014 {
    login = mavis # LDAP
    member = datacomm_read
    pap = login # Clone login
    enable = login # Clone login
    default service = permit
    ###Service read_only START###
    service = shell {
      set priv-lvl = 3
      default attribute = permit
      default cmd = permit
    } #END OF Cisco Router/Switch Service
    ###Service read_only END###
  } #END OF 88014

  user = 82001 {
    login = mavis # LDAP
    member = servicesolution_full
    pap = login # Clone login
    enable = login # Clone login
    default service = permit
    ### GET SERVICES FROM GROUP
  } #END OF 82001

  user = 94003 {
    login = mavis # LDAP
    member = servicesolution_full
    pap = login # Clone login
    enable = login # Clone login
    default service = permit
    ### GET SERVICES FROM GROUP
  } #END OF 94003

  user = 89014 {
    login = mavis # LDAP
    member = datacomm_full
    pap = login # Clone login
    enable = login # Clone login
    default service = permit
    ### GET SERVICES FROM GROUP
  } #END OF 89014

  user = 18001 {
    login = mavis # LDAP
    member = servicesolution_read
    pap = login # Clone login
    enable = login # Clone login
    default service = permit
    ### GET SERVICES FROM GROUP
  } #END OF 18001
}##END GLOBAL CONFIGURATION
```

please help how can i solve this issue without re-installing tacacs server

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue earlier. This is because of the special character in Name. I replace the special character form name and it's working for me.